# Laravel register page not loading

Tags: php, laravel

I have been having this problem for some time now and it is  getting frustrating. Basically, I cannot access the authentication system of laravel at a. I download laravel edit my `.env` file and run `php artisan make:auth`. It doesn't give me any errors but rather it says `Authentication scaffolding generated successfully`.

Thinking its ok,I run `php artisan serve` head on to `localhost:8000` then I click `Register`**.That is when the problem starts.Either `localhost/register` never finishes loading OR it does then I try to register a new user.Click `register` and.....nothing happens.It also never finishes loading.**

My env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:gz6+YOp0gakL+IULqPSdd/ToL4knrErcTCCwujzh4DA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mysite
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=sAhRIcAtorTRasEADERiOn

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Because of that I install laravel  over and over again (this is the 11th time in a row) but the problem doesn't go

Please help

Comment: Have you filled your database details in .env and generated the `app_key` for your laravel application?

Comment: @TauseefShah Yes.But the password is null

Comment: Try to open inspector, Network tab, then reload /register or /login page, if there's 500 server error, then it's php issue. You might have to chmod 777 storage too

Comment: When you say "I download laravel", can you be more specific? If you can show us specifically what you are doing / typing in the console we can be more effective in our answers to help guide you! Perhaps share your .env file, your HomeController and your db structure.

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane I used that `composer create-project laravel/laravel mysite`

Comment: @xDiff might have to what?

Comment: If you navigate to your project directory in the terminal, can you type `ls -l` and update your question with the contents? I think @xDiff might be on to something with the permissions

Comment: Is Composer included in your $PATH? Have you updated your folder permissions? Can you update your question with the contents of your .env file?

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane Yes composer is in the path.How do I update my folder permissions.Ok

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane I am 90% sure that my env file is correct

Comment: I am 100% sure if you want to get this sorted out on SO you'll need to post some code snippets. As for the folder permissions, start by reading [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane No probs

Comment: @Dboss If it's null then leave it blank don't right null

Comment: @xDiff Its response is` stalled` ,pending

Comment: @Dboss Sorry for the technical reply. I meant to say that if it's a server issue, laravel should spit out the error on the screen or a log file, so you might have to change permission of storage folder to writeable. That way, you can see what error is occurring in the php side.

Comment: One other option is to try installing via laravel installer `composer global require laravel/installer` then `laravel new mysite`, see if error will still occur

Answer (score 1):

I'm explaining the steps to generate laravel auth scaffolding in a new laravel application

1) Install or copy Laravel Application from github and put that in your localhost folder and run `composer install` command  in terminal to get the vendors.

2) Copy the files of `.env.example` and paste them in a new file named `.env`

3) Run `php artisan key:generate` to generate a key for you application

4) Setup the database for you application by changing the value for following parameters in `.env` file:

```
/* Note that there must not be any space after "=" sign
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=DATABASE_NAME
DB_USERNAME=DATABASE_USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD=DATABASE_PASSWORD /* Or keep it empty like "DB_PASSWORD=" this if there is no password */
```

5) Run artisan command to generate the auth scaffolding `php artisan make:auth`

6) Then use artisan migration command to create tables in database `php artisan migrate`

These are the 6 steps to use Laravel Auth Scaffolding in a new laravel application. Try this out. Hope it helps you with your problem!!!